# img moving when browser re sized

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have updated this post, as i seem to be facing a new issue with this image problem, basically, i need to center an image on all devices.

Here is the HTML of the images, all images must stay as they are as its a custom menu.

```css
body {  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; background-color:#2d2d2d; color: #f5f5f5; margin: 0 auto; padding:0; font-size:12pt; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; }
}

#box2 {
display:block;
     margin:auto;
     height:500px; /*change ## to the pixel setting of your image*/
     width:500px;/*change ## to the pixel setting of your image*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

body { padding:0; background-image: none !important; }


}
```

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Page Menu
*/
 ?>



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />

<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<style>
body {background-color:black}
</style>

<div id="body">
<div id="box2" "style="position: absolute">
<a href=""><img src="http://www.tridentas.co.uk/tridentascouk/bowwownow/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/111.png" width="500" align="middle"  style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 500px; "/>
<a href="http://tridentas.co.uk/bowwownow"><img src="http://www.tridentas.co.uk/tridentascouk/bowwownow/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/home1.png" width="65"  style="position: absolute; border: 0px solid white; top: 240px; left: 530px; "/></a>
<a href="http://tridentas.co.uk/bowwownow"><img src="http://www.tridentas.co.uk/tridentascouk/bowwownow/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/home1.png" width="65" style="position: absolute; border: 0px solid blue; top: 170px; left: 785px;"/></a>
<a href="http://tridentas.co.uk/bowwownow"><img src="http://www.tridentas.co.uk/tridentascouk/bowwownow/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/home1.png" width="65" style="position: absolute; border: 0px solid green; top: 140px; left: 650px;"/></a>
<a href="http://tridentas.co.uk/bowwownow"><img src="http://www.tridentas.co.uk/tridentascouk/bowwownow/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/home1.png" width="65" style="position: absolute; border: 0px solid red; top: 280px; left: 890px;"/></a>
<a href="http://tridentas.co.uk/bowwownow"><img src="http://www.tridentas.co.uk/tridentascouk/bowwownow/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/home1.png" width="65" style="position: absolute; border: 0px solid purple; top: 435px; left: 565px;"/></a>
<a href="http://tridentas.co.uk/bowwownow"><img src="http://www.tridentas.co.uk/tridentascouk/bowwownow/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/home1.png" width=65" style="position: absolute;  border: 0px solid grey; top: 435px; left: 820px;"/></a>
<a href="http://tridentas.co.uk/bowwownow"><img src="http://www.tridentas.co.uk/tridentascouk/bowwownow/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/home1.png" width="65" style="position: absolute; border: 0px solid yellow; top: 325px; left: 690px;"/></a>
</div>
</div>
```

I just need the main image to be centered on all devices, basically just in the middle of 100% screen width, finding it hard to do so have no idea why

Comment: what do you means by keep images moving when browser resize and if possible create jsfiddle and post here to understand more.

Comment: when i re size my browser the images move out of position, on my browser set to 100% the images are perfect but as soon as i zoom in, or go on a tablet the images are all out of proportion.

Comment: Its hard to understand what it is that you are trying to do here. I can tell you that your layout is really poorly defined you are mixing % based positioning with straight up pixels. Put this on jfiddle and tell us what your browser window size and browser you are using is if you want more help

Comment: In the code above there is a missing quote around a width value.  Also an extra one before the style attribute for the enclosing div.  Just an observation, not necessarily saying that's your main issue.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I had to change some stuff around. Images are bigger than they were you may have to resize as well, but stay in place now.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
body {
background-color: black;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="navigation">
<div "style="position: relative">
<a href="http://tridentas.co.uk/bowwownow">
<img  src="http://www.tridentas.co.uk/tridentascouk/bowwownow/wp-  content/uploads/2015/10/home1.png" style: "width= 65; border: 0px solid white;   top: 22%; left: 42%;"/></a>
<a href="http://tridentas.co.uk/bowwownow">
<img src="http://www.tridentas.co.uk/tridentascouk/bowwownow/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/home1.png" style= "width= 65; border: 0px solid blue; top: 170px; left: 715px;"/></a>
<a href="http://tridentas.co.uk/bowwownow">
<img src="http://www.tridentas.co.uk/tridentascouk/bowwownow/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/home1.png" style= "width= 65; border: 0px solid green; top: 230px; left: 460px;"/></a>
<a href="http://tridentas.co.uk/bowwownow">
<img src="http://www.tridentas.co.uk/tridentascouk/bowwownow/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/home1.png" style= "width= 65; border: 0px solid red; top: 260px; left: 825px;"/></a>
<a href="http://tridentas.co.uk/bowwownow">
<img src="http://www.tridentas.co.uk/tridentascouk/bowwownow/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/home1.png" style= "width= 65; border: 0px solid purple; top: 405px; left: 490px;"/></a>
<a href="http://tridentas.co.uk/bowwownow">
<img src="http://www.tridentas.co.uk/tridentascouk/bowwownow/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/home1.png" style= "width= 65; border: 0px solid grey; top: 405px; left: 760px;" />
</a>
<a href="http://tridentas.co.uk/bowwownow">
<img src="http://www.tridentas.co.uk/tridentascouk/bowwownow/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/home1.png" width="65" style="position: absolute; border: 0px solid yellow; top: 305px; left: 625px;" />
</a>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Must be something to do with my css, i am using wordpress i was just trying jsfiddle, never used it before.

https://jsfiddle.net/tvgy2fxx/1/

Comment: Does that do what you needed it to do? If so please checkmark answer.

Comment: i think it would if i did not have a very large CSS file attached to the site, think i will have to re look over the whole CSS, thanks for the help.

Comment: If the images are too large just change the width and height on them now they will stay in place.